# Checking a Google user's gtalk buddies Presence status in my GAE application, when he's logged in

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, xmpp, google-talk

I'm creating a GAE application, as a part of which, we wish to show logged in Google user - his gtalk buddies list and their presence status.

Google XMPP API let you create bots, but user's gtalk buddies need not share invitation with the app.

Simple things I want to achieve in a GAE application:
1) I authorize using oAuth.
2) Using the token, I fetch that user's gtalk buddies presence and show to him in my GAE app.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The XMPP API on App Engine does not provide that functionality.  It cannot operate on behalf of any arbitray user.

You'll have to look into using another XMPP library.

Comment: Other py XMPP libraries let me do that, but do they work on GAE? When I tried, I couldn't make them work.

Comment: If this solution is not available on GAE, for this thing, I need to put my gtalk presence web service on a non-GAE hosting, whereas rest of my application is on GAE. Isn't that painful?

Comment: You'll have to deal with GAE limitations of a pure python library.  If there's a pure python XMPP library, I'm assuming it can be made to work now that GAE has a new socket API.  In any case, I would expect this to be a fair bit of work.  It sounds like you're expecting to get something for free.

I suspect getting an existing library to work on non-GAE server would actually be less work than getting something like that working around GAE's quirks.

Comment: Its not expecting something free. But yes, I definitely expected inbuilt features enabling easy integration of various pieces of same ecosystem. Is that unfair?